# Shallow & Deep Binding - What would this program print?

Tags: binding, programming-languages, dynamic-binding, static-binding

I'm not sure how to do this...

```
function f1()
{
    var x = 10;
    function f2(fx)
    {
        var x;
        x = 6;
        fx();
    };

    function f3()
    {
        print x;
    };

    f2(f3);
};
```

For each of the following two binding methods, what would the program print?
A)  Shallow Binding
B)  Deep Binding

Thanks for the help!

Comment: see [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1753186/dynamic-scoping-deep-binding-vs-shallow-binding).

in a nutshell: deep binding prints `10` as the binding of `x` takes place when `f2` is called, shallow binding prints `6` as `x` is bound when `f3` (being a procedure parameter to `f2`) is called from `f2`.

Answer (score 26):

Deep/shallow binding makes sense only when a procedure can be passed as an argument to a function.

- **Deep binding** binds the environment at the time a procedure is passed
  as an argument.
- **Shallow binding** binds the environment at the time a
  procedure is actually called.

### **Deep binding.**

Here *f3()* gets the environment of *f1()* and prints the value of *x* as *10* which is local variable of *f1()*.

### **Shallow binding.**

*f3()* is called in *f2()* and hence gets the environment of *f2()* and prints the value of x as 6 which is local to *f2()*

Answer (score 1):

• The environment of the call statement that enacts the passed subprogram
(shallow binding)

• The environment of the definition of the passed subprogram (deep
binding).

In some cases, the subprogram that declares a subprogram also passes that
subprogram as a parameter. In those cases, deep binding and ad hoc binding
are the same.

Answer (score -1):

Shallow binding : the environment of call statement that enacts the passed subprogram
Deep binding : the environment of the definition of the passed subprogram
Ad hoc binding : the environment of call statement that passed the subproblem as an actual parameter